# What is the error message here?

Tags: software-installation, synaptic

While I am trying to update my linux through synaptic package manager,

I found the following error message.
[image]

### Question:

1.What is this?

2. How to get rid of this?

Comment: Please do not post big screenshots with error message somewhere in it, copy and paste error text into your question!

Comment: Synaptic tells you that some mirrors are gone or files on them are no longer in place. You may ignore this unless you do not encounter further breakage.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is: ***Could not download all repository indexes***.

You can see it just to the right of the message icon with the bright red background; just here:

[image]

To get rid of it click the ***Close*** button at the bottom right.

It's this one: [image]

Comment: hah the answer of the day

Comment: how to get rid of this??@mikeserv